# How to add default font-family to Tinymce output html

Tags: jquery, html, fonts, tinymce-4

We are using Tinymce 4.x for text formatting.The output HTML string generated does not contain the font-family of the default text.The output HTML, in this case, is

This is a text string

However if we select a different font family from the drop down it does add up in the html span element.The output string looks like

This is a text string

We would need the default font family of the input text in the output HTML string.We have done a lot of research but was not able to find a working solution help.Appreciate if anyone can help.

**Current code is**

```
       tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode: "textareas",
            height: "167",
            directionality: 'rtl',
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
            body_class: 'arn_richclass',
            statusbar: false,
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: "link textcolor lists directionality",
            removed_menuitems: "newdocument visualaid",
            toolbar: "bold italic underline forecolor bullist link",
            menu: {
                edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
                format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline | formats' }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default TinyMCE is going to use the CSS provided to the editor to control the look of the content - this would include the default fonts, sizes, colors, etc.

If you want some sort of inline style on the root blocks within the content you would need to add those yourself - I don't know of any HTML editor that would add them by default as it defeats the entire ability to control the look of the content via CSS.

Perhaps you could use `forced_root_block` and `forced_root_block_attrs` to set some sort of style attribute on the root blocks?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block_attrs

Something like this in your configuration:

```
forced_root_block : 'p',
forced_root_block_attrs: {
    'class': 'myclass',
    'style': 'font-family: arial times sans-serif; font-weight: bold;'
}
```

Any time the editor inserts a new root block it will get a class and inline styles.